# andengine how to jump a animatedsprite body

Tags: android

i did'nt find the answer of simple question.
i just want to jump my player body.i am trying linervelocity, by doing this player continuous jump(move) in x-axis and go out from screen.i just want small jump in which after touching screen player will jump and return to starting point.
i am doing like this, please help...

```
   public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        playerBody.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(playerBody.getLinearVelocity().x,-5));

return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
playerBody.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(playerBody.getLinearVelocity().x,-5));
```

this means that after you touch the screen you will apply two forces X and Y. You will jump but fall down afterwards because of gravitation force. However there's no X force in your physics world so the attached X force won't be ever countered. This is why player is moving X.

Second reason which I came up to during writing is that you don't check what type of touch it was. Use:

```
if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp())
```

This is more reliable answer

Comment: this is solved by applying gravity, you are great mateusz..
can u please give me your personal email, on which i can contact u further problems..

Comment: feel free to ask on stack overflow. I will answer if I know:)